# Assign 2D list as keys and another 1D list as values to a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list

**I need to assign 2 list of different dimensions to a dictionary as Key Value pairs.**
(It should also store repeated values as of list2 below)

```
list1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

list2 = [0, 1, 1, 2]
```

> dict_output = {[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]:0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]:1, [0, 0,
> 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]:1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]:2}

I have tried using zip but didn't worked.

Comment: The keys of a dictionary cannot be lists. Convert them to tuples then use zip

Comment: it will be fine if keys and values are interchanged. Or is there any possible way to get desired output?

Comment: In this case, you can't interchange them, as the keys will no longer be unique.

Comment: yes it will give me error

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuples as keys:

```
dict_output = dict(zip(map(tuple, list1), list2))
```

output:

```
{(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0): 0,
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 1,
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0): 1,
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0): 2}
```

or, if you want the key/value reversed:

```
dict_output = dict(zip(list2, list1))
```

*NB. but note that that **keys need to be unique**, which is not the case here, so you'll lose some elements*

output:

```
{0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy I'll try to work with this

Comment: Maybe explicit what you're trying to achieve?